# How to change style of Scrollbar in Select Control on HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to change style of Scrollbar in Select Control in HTML?

Comment: Why? (Many) Users hate when a website changes the standard system controls.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set styles to the system elements. They look different in different bowsers and OSs. And you cannot do anything dirctly with them. But you could use some jQuery plugins to replace system elements. [check this](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements)